# why sometimes it's not required to allocate memory in C?

Tags: c, struct

I have seen sometimes people don't allocate memory even if they declare struct as pointer. Why is it so? For example:

```
struct test {
    int a;
    char *b;
    struct _test_2 {
      int d;
      char *f;
    } *test_2;
}
```

1)

```
struct test my_var;
my_var.a = 10;
my_var.b = "test string";    
my_var.test_2->d = 20;
my_var.test_2->f = "test string2"
```

2)

```
struct test my_var;
my_var.a = 10;
my_var.b = "test string";    
my_var.test_2 = (struct _test_2) malloc(sizeof(struct _test_2));
my_var.test_2->d = 20;
my_var.test_2->f = "test string2"

// free it after done
free(my_var.test_2);
```

What is the difference between these two? Which one is a correct way to use it?

Comment: the difference is 2 is correct but 1 is wrong. 1 is writing to random memory and not generating core dump is pure luck.

Comment: Maybe they just like to live dangerously.  Yes, the first example is undefined behavior and likely to make somebody sad sooner or later.

Comment: The first one has undefined behavior, since memory is not allocated. The second one is not even compilable, since `struct test_2` is not a valid type name. There's no such type as `struct test_2` in your code.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Where is in the standard specified that in case 1 one would be writing to this "random memory" (which I assume you do not mean RAM, because otherwise your statement would be trivially true)?

Comment: @nbro random means whatever address that the bit string OS somehow leaves is interpreted to. standard also doesn't say "core dump". you don't have to over-interpret every word in a sentence I typed in 15 seconds, do you?

Comment: @AnT and even if there was, it is not permitted to cast to a struct type

Comment: @nbro section 6.5.2.3/4 of the C11 standard. The behaviour of `->` is only defined for the case where its left-hand operand points to an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is doing proper memory management and the other is not doing it. You're just taking a risk with the first example and hoping your data doesn't get overwritten or malformed. On the second one you properly allocate memory (but you're missing a * on the internal struct allocation).

#2 would be the best choice.

Comment: ..apart from the invalid cast of a struct to a pointer, as commented by Ant above, which will surely result in a compilation fail.